# Terratest does not find terraform on Mac

Tags: macos, terraform, terratest

I am trying to write a simple go test as follows

```
import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestCoreInfoOutput(t *testing.T) {
    terraformOptions := &terraform.Options{
        TerraformDir: "../examples/output.tf",
    }

    defer terraform.Destroy(t, terraformOptions)

    terraform.InitAndApply(t, terraformOptions)

    output := terraform.Output(t, terraformOptions, "test_name_prefix")
    assert.Equal(t, "dev-use1-hello_world-", output)
}
```

But when I run `go test my_test.go` I get the following error

```
    apply.go:13: 
            Error Trace:    apply.go:13
                                        my_test.go:17
            Error:          Received unexpected error:
                            FatalError{Underlying: fork/exec /usr/local/bin/terraform: not a directory}
            Test:           TestCoreInfoOutput
    destroy.go:11: 
            Error Trace:    destroy.go:11
                                        panic.go:615
                                        testing.go:657
                                        apply.go:13
                                        core-info_test.go:17
            Error:          Received unexpected error:
                            FatalError{Underlying: fork/exec /usr/local/bin/terraform: not a directory}
            Test:           my_Test
FAIL
```

Here is the folder structure

```
--module 
    --core-info
      --examples
        --core-info.tf
        --output.tf
      --test
         my_test.go
```

I basically want to test the output values in output.tf in my test.

EDIT:

After I changed the file to be a directory of the file it fails with the follwong error

```
goroutine 23 [IO wait]:
internal/poll.runtime_pollWait(0x9804f28, 0x72, 0xffffffffffffffff)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:203 +0x55
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc00011c7f8, 0x72, 0x1001, 0x1000, 0xffffffffffffffff)
    /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:87 +0x45
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:92
internal/poll.(*FD).Read(0xc00011c7e0, 0xc0001a6000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:169 +0x201
os.(*File).read(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/os/file_unix.go:263
os.(*File).Read(0xc00011a080, 0xc0001a6000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/os/file.go:116 +0x71
bufio.(*Scanner).Scan(0xc000180300, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/scan.go:213 +0xa4
github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/shell.readData(0x13ebf20, 0xc00014a7e0, 0xc000180300, 0xc00011ebc0, 0xc00011eb88, 0xc00012d020)
    /Users/me/go/src/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/shell/command.go:151 +0xc9
created by github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/shell.readStdoutAndStderr
    /Users/me/go/src/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/shell/command.go:135 +0x257
FAIL    command-line-arguments  600.060s
FAIL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TerraformDir` option](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/v0.26.0/modules/terraform/options.go#L12) should be set to a folder path and not a file path.

```
    TerraformDir: "../examples",
```

`"../examples/output.tf"` is not a folder path

Comment: great!!!! That made the test execute but I have two .tf file under the examples folder and the test seem to get stuck at this line ---- ` Running command terraform with args [apply -input=false -auto-approve -lock=false]`

Comment: Edit your question to include the .tf files. Also, do you have the terraform binary in system `PATH`?

Comment: Yes its in my path , and I edited my question to also have the error that it fails with

Comment: What's your version of terraform and what syntax version are your .tf files written in?

Comment: my terraform version is v0.12.24 and I am able to terraform apply the .tf files its only the terratest that fails so horribly

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error with this exact version of terraform. If this isn't yet solved, you may want to provide the go version as well.